# Use several textures with obj model in three.js

Tags: three.js, textures

How can I use two textures with obj model with three.js?

I'm following the obj [webgl_obj_loader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html) example which uses the [male02](http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/examples/obj/male02) obj file.
I want to use two textures for the clothes and face, male-02-1noCulling.JPG and orig_02_-_Defaul1noCulling.JPG.

In the example, it loads a single texture and sets it to the obj children which are THREE.Mesh instances - [child.material.map = texture](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html#L102)

How can I change it to use two textures?
How will three.js know which texture to use for the body and which texture to use for the face?
Is there a format that already encapsulates the model and textures so a single call to three.js will render everything? I would like to have a viewer that can just accept a file exported from a 3D editor and display it.

Thanks